# Can I connect to Memgraph using Go?

Tags: go, memgraphdb

I'd like to connect from Go to the running instance of the Memgraph database. I'm using Docker and I've installed the Memgraph Platform. What exactly do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure for connecting fro Go to Memgraph is rather simple. For this you need to use Bolt protocol. Here are the needed steps:

First, create a new directory for your app, `/MyApp`, and position yourself in it. Next, create a `program.go` file with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/v4/neo4j"
)

func main() {
    dbUri := "bolt://localhost:7687"
    driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver(dbUri, neo4j.BasicAuth("username", "password", ""))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Handle driver lifetime based on your application lifetime requirements  driver's lifetime is usually
    // bound by the application lifetime, which usually implies one driver instance per application
    defer driver.Close()
    item, err := insertItem(driver)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", item.Message)
}

func insertItem(driver neo4j.Driver) (*Item, error) {
    // Sessions are short-lived, cheap to create and NOT thread safe. Typically create one or more sessions
    // per request in your web application. Make sure to call Close on the session when done.
    // For multi-database support, set sessionConfig.DatabaseName to requested database
    // Session config will default to write mode, if only reads are to be used configure session for
    // read mode.
    session := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{})
    defer session.Close()
    result, err := session.WriteTransaction(createItemFn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result.(*Item), nil
}

func createItemFn(tx neo4j.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
    records, err := tx.Run(
        "CREATE (a:Greeting) SET a.message = $message RETURN 'Node ' + id(a) + ': ' + a.message",
        map[string]interface{}{"message": "Hello, World!"})
    // In face of driver native errors, make sure to return them directly.
    // Depending on the error, the driver may try to execute the function again.
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    record, err := records.Single()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // You can also retrieve values by name, with e.g. `id, found := record.Get("n.id")`
    return &Item{
        Message: record.Values[0].(string),
    }, nil
}

type Item struct {
    Message string
}
```

Now, create a `go.mod` file using the `go mod init example.com/hello` command.
I've mentioned the Bolt driver earlier. You need to add it with `go get github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/v4@v4.3.1`. You can run your program with `go run .\program.go`.

The complete documentation is located at [Memgraph site](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/go).